# Sub-Tree totals in Clojure Tree functions

Tags: clojure, tree, functional-programming, lisp

Hi im hoping i can get some help, i am trying to pass in an input

```
User==> (biggest-branch  [[1 [3 2]] [1 [8 8]]])
```

and what i am trying to do is go through the tree and return the sub-tree which contains the biggest maximum total.  So in this case it would return the subtree with 1+8+8

I have tried to implement it with the following code and it compiles, but im having problems with getting it to work,  i know the code isnt really up to scratch as im pretty new at the lanugage so can anyone help me out in trying to fix my solution??

```
(defn leaf [leaf]
 leaf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Comments on your code:

- `(seq? [])` returns `false`. You want to use `coll?`.
- Your `sum-tree` function has what looks like a syntax error which is probably why you're getting an error. I'd recommend working in an environment that can do auto-indentation and use that feature as much as possible. It should reveal such problems sooner.
- Each branch is a tree. You've recognised this to some degree but not taken it all the way. There's no need for a separate `branch-total` and `sum-tree` function as they're the same thing.
- The `leaf` function isn't necessary. It's the same function as `identity`.

---

This should be all the code required:

```
(defn sum-tree [tree]
  (if (coll? tree)
    (apply + (map sum-tree tree))
    tree))

(defn biggest-branch [tree]
  (apply max-key sum-tree tree))

(biggest-branch [[1 [3 2]] [1 [8 8]]])
; => [1 [8 8]]
```

Take a look at the doc for [max-key](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/max-key).